# How to deploy multiple MEAN app containers to Azure using Docker-Compose

Tags: node.js, angularjs, azure, docker, docker-compose

I am pretty new to docker. I am trying to deploy a MEAN app (Angular frontend, Node.js/Express backend, and MongoDB) to Azure using Docker-Compose.

Locally the multi container environment works as expected. The front-end connects to the back-end web api and db as expected. When I deploy the image to Azure the front-end cannot connect to the back-end web api's.

The error in the browser console is:

> OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/api/dosa net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Angular Docker file

```
FROM node:8.12-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/front-end
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/front-end

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/front-end/

RUN npm install
RUN npm install -g @angular/cli

COPY . /usr/src/app/front-end

CMD ng serve --host 0.0.0.0 --port 4200 --disable-host-check
```

Node.js Docker File

```
FROM node:8.12-alpine

RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app/back-end
WORKDIR /usr/src/app/back-end

ENV PATH /usr/src/app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY package*.json /usr/src/app/back-end/

RUN npm install

COPY . /usr/src/app/back-end

CMD npm start
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '2.1'

services:
  client: # name of the service
    image: {{myDockerRepo}}/frontend:dev
    build: frontend
    expose:
        - 4200
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: production
    ports:
      - 4200:4200
    links:
      - server

  server:
      image: {{myDockerRepo}}/backend:dev
      build: ./backend
      expose:
        - 3000
      environment:
        NODE_ENV: production
      ports:
        - 3000:3000
      links:
      - database

  database:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - "27017:27017"
```

api.service.ts calls

```
const dosaApiUrl = "http://localhost:3000/api/dosa";
getDoSAs(): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(dosaApiUrl, { headers: this.httpOptionsWAuth() }).pipe(
      map(this.extractData),
      catchError(this.handleError));
  }
```

I run the following via azure cli

```
az webapp create --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myPlan --name MyWebApp --multicontainer-config-type compose --multicontainer-config-file docker-compose.yml
```

Azure docker-compose log (condensed)

```
2019-01-13 14:35:43.461 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-01-13 14:35:43.461 INFO  - docker run -d -p 12574:4200 --name MyWebApp_client_5 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=MyWebApp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=206aa27402c709921f82d12a9fc0030a987d4d1f7523a0723759d8b10b751860 myDockerRepo/frontend:dev  

2019-01-13 14:35:45.812 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-01-13 14:35:45.812 INFO  - docker run -d -p 0:3000 --name MyWebApp_server_5 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=MyWebApp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=206aa27402c709921f82d12a9fc0030a987d4d1f7523a0723759d8b10b751860 myDockerRepo/backend:dev  

2019-01-13 14:35:47.026 INFO  - Starting container for site
2019-01-13 14:35:47.026 INFO  - docker run -d -p 0:27017 --name MyWebApp_database_5 -e WEBSITE_SITE_NAME=MyWebApp -e WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED=False -e WEBSITE_ROLE_INSTANCE_ID=0 -e WEBSITE_INSTANCE_ID=206aa27402c709921f82d12a9fc0030a987d4d1f7523a0723759d8b10b751860 mongo  

2019-01-13 14:35:47.026 INFO  - Logging is not enabled for this container.
Please use https://aka.ms/linux-diagnostics to enable logging to see container logs here.
2019-01-13 14:38:45.686 INFO  - Started multi-container app
2019-01-13 14:38:45.760 INFO  - Container MyWebApp_client_5 for site MyWebApp initialized successfully.
```

I can call the back-end web api's fine locally using docker-compose up --build but it doesn't work when deployed to Azure

Comment: Any more question? Or if it's helpful you can accept it as the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you deploy multi-containers on Azure, there is something different from that you deploy the multi-containers on local Docker server.

You can use the Docker compose setting `links` to bind the web application and the backend server or other services. But on Azure, it most dependants on the environment. There is an example that [Creating a multi-container app in Web App for Containers on Azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-multi-container-app). The sample compose file like this:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
volumes:
    db_data:
```

You can follow the steps in it and do some modifications in your compose file according to your requirement. Hope this will help you.